# Pre-Trained model to extract the feature of the images tensorflow?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

Could someone please provide details of model available to extract the feature of images model for tensorflow or Keras? I have been looking for pre-trained models that will extract the features of the image. And then I will create a vector of the images then apply the nearest neighbor to find out similar images.

Comment: How is `autoencoder` a tag.?

Answer (score 1):

Any ordinary pre-trained classification model like vgg or resNet will extract different features of the image on each layer. While the earlier layers will respond to more basic and simple features like edges, the deeper layers will respond to more specific features. If you want to have specific features extracted from images, you have to label some data and train your model with that dataset. 
For that, you can use the first couple of layers from a pre-trained model as an encoder.

But I would guess a CNN only solution will get you better results. Here is a nice read about the subject: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1709/1709.08761.pdf

Keras actually includes some applications with pre-trained weights, including vgg16: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py

There you can find the link to the weights for this vgg16 model (pre-trained on imageNet):
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5

Comment: Thanks. What are the features of the image can be extracted? I believe RGB value is one of the feature

Comment: @sakthivel The learned weights and bias (params) of specific layers of a learned CNN are more robust than simple global features like the RGB value, because there you learn more complex and nonlinear features. Just read the linked paper which Jodo recommend in his answer. In addition you can read the following tutorial which explains a simple autoencoder https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html.